# How to finish sys.stdin.readlines() input?

Tags: python, input, interactive, sys

This might be a silly question, but as I can't find an answer, I have to ask it.

In interactive python I want to process a message which i get with:

```
>>> message = sys.stdin.readlines()
```

Everything works fine, but... how to stop it from getting an input and  make it save into message variable? Stopping with ctrl+c stops whole process so there is no input to be saved anywhere. I guess there's an easy answer I just can't find...

Answer (score 73, accepted):

**For UNIX based systems (Linux, Mac):**

Hello, you can type : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> closes the standard input (stdin) by sending [EOF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file).

Example :

```
>>> import sys
>>> message = sys.stdin.readlines()
Hello
World
My
Name
Is
James
Bond
# <ctrl-d> EOF sent
>>> print message
['Hello\n', 'World\n', 'My\n', 'Name\n', 'Is\n', 'James\n', 'Bond\n']
```

**For Windows :**

To send EOF on Windows, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>

Answer (score 7):

This is an old question but it needs an update about **Windows and different keyboard layouts.**

If neither **CTRL + Z** nor **CTRL + D ** work for you on Windows** and and you're wandering what is going on do this:

- check if you are using **default english keyboard layout**
- if you do have different, non-default keyboard layout try switching keyboard setting to English in language bar, then try pressing ctrl + z after changes
- if you're still confused look at the screen, what appears in command line when you press ctrl + z. What symbol do you see? When I was pressing ctrl + z I was seeing this: ^Y, and when by mistake I pressed ctrl + y I've seen this ^Z, i pressed enter and the input was taken, EOF sent.

This is somewhat strange and counterintuitive. I changed keys layout some time ago to include polish characters, but all the common keys are left unchanged, z still maps to z when I use the keyboard normally, normally ctrl + z does nothing in my keyboard, so I shouldn't be changed. But apparently in cmd it works differently, in order to have default link between ctrl and z I have to switch to default layout, or use control y to sent EOF.

Answer (score 7):

On windows simply do CTRL+Z and press enter

Answer (score 6):

Use `CTRL-D`.

```
message = sys.stdin.readlines()
abc
def
<CTRL-D>

# message == ['abc\n', 'def\n']
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are a Mac user, please use command + D. It works!

Answer (score 1):

I tested that in VS code terminal.

After using this command:

```
for line in stdin:
```

I input many lines of data. Keep pressing Enter does not work now.

Solution:

Press **Ctrl + Z**, you will see ^Z in the terminal.

Then you have to **press Enter** to finish.