# How can I work with input flow in Pycharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I'm new to Python and using Pycharm to work with code.

I'm writing a simple program, that read string and then convert it into int.

```
import sys

    print ("Hello word")
    data = sys.stdin.read()
    tokens = data.split()

    for i in range(len(tokens)):
        tokens[i] = int(tokens[i])

    print (tokens[1])
```

[image]

I ran program, entered three numbers, but that's all 
Why, while running the program I can't see the results of print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the program is still reading from `stdin`. To read only one line from `stdin`, you have to use `stdin.readline()`. If you run a debug process with a breakpoint after the line `sys.stdin.read()`, you'll see that the program never reaches it. Running your program in Ideone, for example, where it lets you specify stdin before running your app, `stdin.read()` works fine. Usually it reads until EOF (end of file). So, either use `sys.stdin.readline()` (built-in `input()` does just that), or use file input if you want to read multiple lines. You can also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549141/how-to-finish-sys-stdin-readlines-input) post for more info if you really want to use `sys.stdin.read()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have effectively blocked the program with `.read()`; its a lot simpler to use `input()`, like this:

```
print('Hello World')
data = input()
tokens = map(int, data.split()) # this converts to int
print(tokens[1])
```