# Using sys.stdin.readline() to read multiple lines from cmd in Python

Tags: python, stdin

I'd like to type in my input from command lines after running

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split()))
    print(data)
    n, capacity = data[0:2]
    values = data[2:(2 * n + 2):2]
    weights = data[3:(2 * n + 2):2]
```

A sample input could be:

```
2 40
20 2
30 3
```

My questions are:
1) How to create the list data using my input?
2) How can I let Python know I have finished the input and it should execute the rest of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem depends on the OS you're using.
Basically, if you want multiline input, you'll have to use `sys.stdin.read()` instead of `sys.stdin.readline()`. Since `sys.stdin` is a file-like object in Python, the `read()` method will read until it reaches the end of a file. It is marked by a special character `EOF` (end-of-file). On different OS'es there is a different way of sending it.

**On Windows**:
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> after your input and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
2 10
20 2
30 3
^Z
```

**On a Unix-based OS**:
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> after your input. No <kbd>Enter</kbd> is required (I believe)

If you want to get a list `[2, 10, 20, 2, 30, 3]` from your input, you're fine. The `split()` method splits by whitespace (spaces, newlines, etc.).

Comment: Thanks @Leva7, ctrl + D works. I got the result I want!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everything @Leva7 has said. Nonetheless, I'd suggest another solution, which is to use `raw_input` for Python 2 or `input` for Python 3 like so:

```
args = []
s = raw_input()                # input() for Python 3
while s != '':
    args.extend([int(arg) for arg in s.strip().split()])
    s = raw_input()
```

Of course, that's not a one-liner in any way, but it does the job and it's easy to see how it's done. Plus, no special characters are required at the end of the input.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows make sure you finish your input with newline, otherwise ^Z (from pressing Ctrl-Z) will be included in your input.
Also make sure you use English language layout - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17924627/9205085