# How to combine file input from the command line and user input

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having trouble prompting the user for input after I have already read a file from the command line. My code looks something like this but I get an EOFError every time. Am I missing something? My code:

```
import sys
file = sys.stdin.read().splitlines()
print (file)
name = input("Input your name: ")
print (name)
```

Here is what I put into the command line for these lines:

```
python3 tester.py < example_file.txt
['my file']
Input your name: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tester.py", line 4, in <module>
name = input("Input your name: ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

In this case, I believe I get out of the sys.stdin.read().splitlines() line given that it correctly prints out the information in file. However, once the line containing input() is executed, I am not prompted to input anything and I get an error without pausing to input like normal.

Comment: Please show more representative code and input.

Comment: I updated it a bit. Does that give you a better idea of what's going on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to finish sys.stdin.readlines() input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549141/how-to-finish-sys-stdin-readlines-input)

Comment: @PedroCastilho: That does not solve this issue. How do you read a complete file from stdin then switch to reading stdin interactively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [fileinput module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/fileinput.html) to handle multiple streams a little easier.

```
import fileinput

t_list=[line for line in fileinput.input()]
print(t_list)

name=input('name? ')
print(name)
```

Then run with the file name, not the string contents of the file:

```
$ python3 test.py file
['my file\n']
name? bob
bob
```

Comment: Excellent! Just what I was looking for and thank you for the repeated help!

Comment: If that is helpful to you, please [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)